# Using prim.box in R

Tags: r

I am looking to use `prim.box` for a bump-hunting process in R. I am on a Mac so I downloaded XQuartz, which provided some 3d graphics tools I needed in order to use the package prim properly.

```
install.packages("PRIMsrc")

require(PRIMsrc)

install.packages("prim")

require("prim") 

prim.box(Real.1)
```

> Error in do.call(y.fun, list(x = y)) : argument "y" is missing,
>   with no default

So I'm looking for what I need to assign y to in order to make this work. Thank you!

Comment: Without your code it's quite hard to help you. Could you provide a minimal example ? See here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for the comment -- I just edited the question adding in the entire code.

Comment: Well did you look to the prim package documentation ? It is clearly said what you have to pass for y. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prim/prim.pdf (page 7)